# Xcode 5 crashes while opening the .xib files developed in Xcode 4.6?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, xcode5, xcode4.5

Please help me anyone. I have xcode 4.6 project then now I want to upgrade the code to ios 7, so I am compiling the project in Xcode 5 . But everytime it shows an error in .xib file and when I open that file Xcode get crashed.How can I fix the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI: [Starting February 1, 2015, new iOS apps uploaded to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK, included in **Xcode 6 or later**.](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=10202014a)

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that the desired option is selected.

Note: I am using Xcode 6.

[image]

Comment: I doubt the option to select version 6.0 exists in Xcode 5.

Comment: Sorry, my answer was a bit vague. I have updated it.

Comment: I cannot change the settings in interface builder document. Because I can't open the .xib file in xcode 5.

Comment: @AshrafTawfeeq The Opens in settings is already in Default (6.0). Every time Xcode crash while I am open the .xib files.